# How can I get value from SpinButton in PyGtk?

Tags: python-2.7, spinner, pygtk, glade

I'm developing an ubuntu-application using PyGtk 3 and Glade. I've made a spin button, which I want to get integer values entered by users. But I don't know how can I get the value?

```
    self.fontSize = self.builder.get_object("fontSize")
...
def on_fontSize_value_changed(self, button):
        size = Gtk.SpinButton.get_value_as_int()
        print size
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the `on_fontSize_value_changed` function and now it's working fine:

```
        self.fontSize = self.builder.get_object("fontSize")
        ...
    def on_fontSize_value_changed(self, SpinButton):
            size = self.fontSize.get_value_as_int()
            print size
```